# How do I navigate back form a subsite to the site collection

Tags: navigation, site-collection

I've created a site collection and under it I created a site (both with the Team Site template).
The site collection has a link to the site but the site doesn't seem to have any back link to its parent site collection.

How do I navigate back?
Of course I can use the browser's Back key or simply retype the site-collection's URL but I hope there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's best to inherit the top navigation from the parent site (that's why it isn't default), which usually contains a link to "Home", but otherwise you can use the navigate up button:
[image]

Comment: Both methods don't seem to work for a site created with a Search Site template, though.

Comment: No a Search site uses an annoying master page which has no navigation. If you want to be able to get back, then you have to add a web part with a link :-(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sharepointblog.co.uk/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-breadcrumb.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.